# Why browser forced direction rtl even when I set direction ltr in a rtl language?

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing some i18n work for my react project. And one of the languages I need to process is Arabic(ar-EG), a rtl language. However, that is some text I need to reverse again, so I used the css property `direction: ltr` for it. Like this:

```css
html[lang="ar-EG"] .text {
  direction: ltr
}
```

But when I checked the css style in chrome devtools, I found the property changed to `direction: rtl` again. Then I opened the css chunk file, I found the css compiled result was like this:

```css
/* the project use css modules */

html[dir=ltr][lang="ar-EG"] .text-jhx4 {
  direction: ltr
}
html[dir=rtl][lang="ar-EG"] .text-jhx4 {
  direction: rtl
}
```

Why this happend? It seemed that my custom css couldn't work and the browser recomputed the `direction` property, making it change to `rtl` based on the language.